# How to change the default tx fee cap in Ethers.js, to avoid getting error like "tx fee (4.0 ether) exceeds the configured cap (1.00 ether)"

Tags: polygon, web3js, ethers.js

I'm trying to execute a smart-contract batch processing function but after a certain point of time I'm getting the following error:

```
processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":52,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"tx fee (4.00 ether) exceeds the configured cap (1.00 ether)\"}}", error={"code":-32000}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_sendRawTransaction\",
```

I do look for the same and got a link: [tx fee (2.11 ether) exceeds the configured cap (1.00 ether), how to bypass default cap?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99034/tx-fee-2-11-ether-exceeds-the-configured-cap-1-00-ether-how-to-bypass-defau) but the answer is specific to local net and geth, I'm using Ethers.js for making a call on polygon and avalanche c-chain network, and wanted to know how can I able to change the default configuration in default provider. Below is the code:

```js
async function createTransactionData(arg: any[]) {
    const transferABI = ["function batchSafeMint(address toAddress, uint256[] tokenIds, string[] uris)"];
    const transferInterface = new ethers.utils.Interface(transferABI);
    const transferData = transferInterface.encodeFunctionData(
        'batchSafeMint',
        [
            arg[0],
            arg[1],
            arg[2]
        ]
    );

    return transferData
}

    const transferData = await createTransactionData(params)
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(network.networkURL)
    const gasFeeData = await provider.getFeeData();
    const nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(senderAddress);
    const chainId = (await provider.getNetwork()).chainId;
    const rawTxn: any = {
        to: contractHash,
        maxFeePerGas: gasFeeData.maxFeePerGas,
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: gasFeeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas,
        chainId: chainId,
        data: transferData,
        gasPrice: null,
        nonce: nonce,
        value: null,
        from: senderAddress,
        type: 2
    }
    rawTxn["gasLimit"] = await provider.estimateGas(rawTxn)
    delete rawTxn["from"]

    const unsignedTxn = await ethers.utils.resolveProperties(rawTxn);

    const keccak256Hash = await getUnsignedTxnKeccak256Hash(unsignedTxn);
    const signedTxn = await signer.sign(keccak256Hash); // implemented own signer


    const signedTxnRaw = ethers.utils.serializeTransaction(
        //@ts-ignore
        <UnsignedTransaction>unsignedTxn,
        signedTxn
    );

    const receipt = await provider.sendTransaction(signedTxnRaw);
    let result = await provider.waitForTransaction(receipt.hash);
```

So I have seen at the time of creating a provider there is an option to provide a ConnectionInfo object as well.

```js
// Exported Types
export type ConnectionInfo = {
    url: string,
    headers?: { [key: string]: string | number }

    user?: string,
    password?: string,

    allowInsecureAuthentication?: boolean,
    allowGzip?: boolean,

    throttleLimit?: number,
    throttleSlotInterval?: number;
    throttleCallback?: (attempt: number, url: string) => Promise<boolean>,

    skipFetchSetup?: boolean;
    errorPassThrough?: boolean;

    timeout?: number,
};
```

By any chance can I use config `params`  to change the default config?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another node or run your own node without limiting the --rpc.txfeecap

The node you are using seems to have the --rpc.txfeecap default value, which is 1.0 ethers.

You cannot solve this in ethers.js or in your JavaScript code, sorry.